# Videogular Player shows filmstrips on Android-Smartphone

Tags: android, cordova, video, ionic-framework, videogular

I am in the final steps on my first Ionic-App and I am using the videogular-player.

So far everything works fine but I see a strange bug/feature on my Samsung S5 mini android phone. everytime I am opening my "MediaPlayer-Player"-page, where the videogular-player is integrated I see this strange filmstrips-picture in the background. Also I got an overlay-play not from videogular.

For a test I hide every videogular-plugin like poster and overlayplay and I still see this picture.

Does anybody has an idea where it could come from?

Here is the picture I mentioned:
[image]

Comment: It could be a codec issue. Did you tried the same video without Videogular? Just try to put the video inside a plain video tag.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. When I try it with the video-tag the picture is also shown. So it looks like it is something with ionic or cordova, maybe some default-Pic or something. The bad thing is that I can't see it in my Browser, only on the device. So I am not able to analyse the code. 

Do you have an idea or an tip for me?

Comment: Meanwhile I found a solution and i found the reason for the problem:
[link](http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/78586868260/getting-the-html5-video-tag-to-work-in-cordova-for)

I overwrite with CSS the videogular CSS and then it works fine on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here the final solution. The problem comes from the missing poster-attribute in the video-html-tag. So i just added the following code in my videogular.js, where I do all the configs with my own controller and everything works fine. The only problem that is still here, is the second-overlay-play.

```
    that.onPlayerReady = function(API) {
        that.API = API;
        that.API.mediaElement.attr("poster", "./img/1x1.png");
    };
```